# org.apache.jasper.JasperException How can remove

Tags: jsp

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "${user.dob}" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "value": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:884)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.user_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(user_jsp.java:183)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.user_jsp._jspService(user_jsp.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at com.daniel.controller.UserController.doGet(UserController.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "${user.dob}" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "value": **Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `'${user.dob}'` instead of `"${user.dob}"`.It is treating as a string

Comment: thanks..!! but its not working.. PF my jsp code below..
 DOB : <input
            type="text" name="dob"
            value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='MM/dd/yyyy' value='${user.dob}' />" /> <br />

Comment: PF my jsp code below.. DOB : <input type="text" name="dob" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='MM/dd/yyyy' value='${user.dob}' />" /> <br />

Comment: same exception you are getting

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "${user.dob}" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "value": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:884)
This is what i am getting

Answer (score 1):

please make sure you specified the correct uri in your taglib directive.  Make sure you specified:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>.
```

Instead of:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
```

And specified:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```